# MYSQL and Node.js multiple record insert with where clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, multiple-insert

I am trying to insert multiple records into MYSQL from Node.js with a WHERE clause but I keep getting a syntax error.

The statement works fine until I try to add a conditional statement to it. Then I get this error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax near VALUES ? WHERE ...

```
var Data = data; // this is a nested array already as received from client side like [[..],[..],[..]]
var ID = 123; 

 var sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5) VALUES ? WHERE"+ID+" NOT IN (SELECT somecol FROM table2 WHERE somecol= "+ID+")"

connection.query(sql, [Data], function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
        res.json({ Message: "Oops something went wrong :("});
    }

    res.json({ Message: "Your data was added!"});
});
```

The connection is set up to allow multiple statements already:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '1234',
    database: 'thedb',
    port: 12345,
    charset: "utf8mb4",
    multipleStatements: true
});
```

The query works in this form without the WHERE clause:

```
var Data = data; // this is a nested array already as received from client side like [[..],[..],[..]]
var ID = 123; 

var sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5) VALUES ?"

connection.query(sql, [Data], function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
        res.json({ Message: "Oops something went wrong :("});
    }

    res.json({ Message: "Your data was added!"});
});
```

How do I get the query work with the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Insert` command will not work with `Where` clause because you are inserting a new row. In naive terms, a `Where` clause needs some rows to filter out based on the conditions. Based on your use case you can have two possible solutions:

1. Use `Update` statements which could be like 
   `Update table set col1=val1 where (condition clause)`
2. If you really want to use `Where` clause then you can use the `Insert` command in the following form

`Insert into table(col1,col2) 
Select (val1, val2) from table2 where (condition clause);`

Comment: Ah yes thank you very much somehow I did not see that !